# Creating a Login program

Tags: java

So I recently began learning how to code in java and ive been tasked with trying to create just some beginner programs, such as this one. The goal of this program is to have the user input "admin" as the Username and input "securePassword" as the password and have the output be (if entered correctly) "Welcome" or "Wrong Combination" if entered incorrectly. Every time I compile all I get is "Wrong Combination". My question is how to do I get my program to function correctly, at this point, obviously I have done something wrong, I just do not know what.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login
{
    public static void main( String args [ ] )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // input admin as Username
        System.out.println( "Username: ");
        String userOne = scan.next( );

        // input securePassword as Password
        System.out.println( "Password: ");
        String passOne = scan.next( ); 

        // identify user as the admin
        String user = "admin ";

        //identify pass as securePassword
        String pass = "securePassword ";

        // output if entered inccorectly or correctly
        if (userOne.equals(user) && passOne.equals(pass)) 
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        else 
            System.out.println("Wrong combination");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want `user` to be `"admin "` and not `"admin"`? Notice the lack of space at the end of it. Also - why double assign the `user` and `pass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in your admin:

```
// identify user as the admin
String user = "admin ";
**user = "admin ";**

//identify pass as securePassword
String pass = "securePassword ";
pass = "securePassword";
```

change to `user = "admin";` or trim the assigned value

you can see your password does not have the space

```
// identify user as the admin
String user = "admin ";
user = "admin ";

//identify pass as securePassword
String pass = "securePassword ";
**pass = "securePassword";**
```

You could accomplish this without reassigning as well:

```
// identify user as the admin
String user = "admin";

//identify pass as securePassword
String pass = "securePassword";
```

Comment: My goodness, thanks you so much Josh Adams. What a silly mistake I did not catch.

Comment: @Xzavier glad i could help! if this helps please mark as answer. Enjoy your coding journey!